# 並列処理すると1つの処理が重くなる

Tags: scala

並列で実行すると、1つの処理が重くなってしまいます。

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

// 処理時間を計測する関数 
scala> def elapsed(f: => Unit) = { val s = new java.util.Date; f; println("time: " + (new java.util.Date().getTime - s.getTime) + "ms") }
elapsed: (f: => Unit)Unit

// 何か重い処理
scala> def f = (1 to 1000000).map(_ + scala.util.Random.nextInt(10000))
f: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]

// 普通に30回重い処理を実行
scala> (1 to 30).foreach { _ => elapsed(f) }
time: 166ms
time: 84ms
time: 36ms
time: 35ms
time: 64ms
time: 55ms
time: 52ms
time: 55ms
time: 54ms
time: 54ms
time: 58ms
time: 54ms
time: 52ms
time: 53ms
time: 51ms
time: 56ms
time: 57ms
time: 52ms
time: 63ms
time: 56ms
time: 54ms
time: 70ms
time: 72ms
time: 55ms
time: 119ms
time: 106ms
time: 99ms
time: 86ms
time: 93ms
time: 61ms

// 今度はparで並列に実行
scala> (1 to 30).par.foreach { _ => elapsed(f) }
time: 201ms
time: 212ms
time: 215ms
time: 221ms
time: 176ms
time: 217ms
time: 226ms
time: 251ms
time: 242ms
time: 230ms
time: 235ms
time: 268ms
time: 238ms
time: 235ms
time: 235ms
time: 383ms
time: 372ms
time: 382ms
time: 396ms
time: 414ms
time: 407ms
time: 337ms
time: 324ms
time: 354ms
time: 390ms
time: 407ms
time: 452ms
time: 159ms
time: 147ms
time: 37ms
```

parでの例ですが、Futureでやっても同じような現象でした。

コア数は4つなので並列度は4ですが、さらに並列度を上げると比例してしてさらに重くなります。

処理時間が10倍〜とかなるので、10秒だと100秒とかになって...。

"PCって色々アプリ動かすと急に重くなるよね"みたいな当たり前の現象なのかな...と思ったりもするんですが、よく分かってません...。

何か回避策みたいなものがあるんでしょうか。

詳しい方ご教授ください。よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 7):

- scala.util.Randomは[java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/api/java/util/Random.html)を使うので複数スレッドから同時にアクセスする用途には向かない。
- `(1 to 1000000).map(..)`で大量にメモリが確保される。

という理由で性能出ていないようです。[ThreadLocalRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html)とforeachに書き換えるとオーバーヘッドはありますが、質問の例よりは改善されます。

```
scala> def f5 = (1 to 1000000).foreach(_ => java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10000))

f5: Unit

scala> (1 to 30).foreach { _ => elapsed(f5) }
time: 21ms
time: 31ms
time: 19ms
time: 22ms
time: 17ms
time: 17ms
time: 20ms
time: 19ms
time: 24ms
time: 21ms
time: 17ms
time: 21ms
time: 17ms
time: 20ms
time: 17ms
time: 17ms
time: 29ms
time: 25ms
time: 25ms
time: 17ms
time: 17ms
time: 30ms
time: 36ms
time: 19ms
time: 17ms
time: 18ms
time: 19ms
time: 17ms
time: 20ms
time: 16ms

scala> (1 to 30).par.foreach { _ => elapsed(f5) }
time: 53ms
time: 53ms
time: 54ms
time: 56ms
time: 62ms
time: 63ms
time: 69ms
time: 74ms
time: 51ms
time: 43ms
time: 51ms
time: 50ms
time: 59ms
time: 43ms
time: 55ms
time: 50ms
time: 37ms
time: 40ms
time: 43ms
time: 42ms
time: 37ms
time: 46ms
time: 41ms
time: 35ms
time: 32ms
time: 34ms
time: 37ms
time: 32ms
time: 30ms
time: 30ms
```

Answer (score 4):

純粋に計算負荷をかけるタスクにすると、想定された動きをします。

```
// weightの値は処理性能に合わせて調整してください。30前後が良さそう。
def f(weight: Int): Unit = {
  def fib(n: Int): Int = n match {
    case 0 => 1
    case 1 => 1
    case _ => fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)
  }
  fib(weight)
}

// ついでにThread IDも出す表示関数にします
def elapsed(f: => Unit) = {
    val s = new java.util.Date;
    f;
    println("thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "\ttime:\t" + (new java.util.Date().getTime - s.getTime) + "ms")
}
```

```
// 外側のelapsedが最後に合計を表示
scala> elapsed((1 to 30).foreach { _ => elapsed(f(30)) })
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   4ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   4ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   6ms
thread: 1       time:   6ms
thread: 1       time:   7ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   4ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   5ms
thread: 1       time:   152ms

scala> elapsed((1 to 30).par.foreach { _ => elapsed(f(30)) })
thread: 56      time:   5ms
thread: 58      time:   5ms
thread: 49      time:   5ms
thread: 56      time:   5ms
thread: 58      time:   4ms
thread: 49      time:   5ms
thread: 54      time:   13ms
thread: 56      time:   5ms
thread: 58      time:   5ms
thread: 49      time:   4ms
thread: 54      time:   5ms
thread: 56      time:   4ms
thread: 58      time:   5ms
thread: 49      time:   5ms
thread: 54      time:   4ms
thread: 56      time:   5ms
thread: 49      time:   5ms
thread: 58      time:   5ms
thread: 55      time:   5ms
thread: 56      time:   5ms
thread: 49      time:   5ms
thread: 58      time:   5ms
thread: 55      time:   5ms
thread: 56      time:   5ms
thread: 55      time:   5ms
thread: 57      time:   4ms
thread: 56      time:   4ms
thread: 59      time:   4ms
thread: 58      time:   9ms
thread: 49      time:   9ms
thread: 1       time:   42ms
```

(出力例のスレッドIDが大きいのは、何度か走らせたらIDが大きくなっただけなので、気にしないでください。並列度8)

元々遅くなっていたのは、scala.util.Randomの挙動に起因する問題に思えます。もし実際のアプリケーションでRandomを使う必要があるなら、実装を追って原因追究しないといけません。
そうではなくて並列化の挙動を見たいだけなら、挙動を良く知らないものは使わないほうが無難でしょう。